# What should i do with my own theorem?

Tags: reference-request

I don't know whether I should ask this question here or nor but I will really appreciate if someone answered it.
Although I am a teenager, I am lucky to have discovered a theorem in Mathematics. The discovery was made about 7 months ago but I could neither expose it nor I knew how to publish it because I am a 9th grade student and don't know about publishing a theorem. Please tell me what should i do.

Comment: You can go to arxiv.org or vixra.org and post it.

Comment: The first thing I would recommend is see if it was already discovered before. When I was in class 6, I discovered pascal's triangle only to find that it was long discovered before.

Comment: @Anachor  I have searched in all math but did not find a theorem like that.

Comment: @user3313320: Note that arXiv doesn't publish every article even if after endorsement. This is especially true if the user doesn't have a conventional publication record.

Comment: @user258250 When you say in all math, what exactly do you mean? I mean, to what extent have you searched. I mean, I don't want to take any credit away from you, to discover something at an young age is certainly wonderful. But if it happens that you are talking about something wellknown, people will discredit you. However, whether or not it is known before, you should deserve appreciation because you discovered it independently.

Comment: Type the theorem and its proof in a readable form and upload it to vixra.org. Now that you have established authorship, post the result to math.stackexchange for either criticism or praise depending on the validity and originality of the work.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not it has been discovered before, discovering something independently reflects positively on you. Search more before you publish, there's no rush. I discovered many things through experimentation with various physics equations, and although they'd all, mostly been discovered or mentioned before, I still had a greater understanding of the implications of the equations. Personal discovery is a benefit all on its own, because you can achieve a greater understanding of the material and laws being used.

Comment: @Anachor I mean the particular subject in which i discovered it.

Comment: In any case, I would recommend showing it to someone who is knowledgeable on the topic and is trusted by you. Alternately,  @UmbertoP.'s suggestion looks quite viable, however I have no knowledge on the trustworthiness of vixra.org since I have never used it before. Maybe Umberto can clarify on that.

Comment: The fact that you discovered the theorem on your own is sheer genius.I encourage you to keep up the good work,you might be one of the greatest mathematicians one day,who knows.